# Ways and steps to debug custom event handler code if any

Tags: core-service, event-system

Want to know Ways and steps to debug custom event handler code something developer can do.

am using VS 2012(user machine not where the Tridion CMS hosted) for developing custom event handler code with logging. but thought of checking, is there a way to debug from user machine?.if so what are all the steps for that ?.

Comment: have you googled, you must have found following http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/debugging-tridion-2011-event-system.html

Comment: And that looks like an Answer to me.

Comment: Thanks for links Raj,Rick am new to tridion so thought of getting steps for getting and attaching process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you googled, you must have found following http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/debugging-tridion-2011-event-system.html

Answer (score 4):

And to complement Raj's answer (Google is your friend): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You will have good directions from google on setting up and debugging Tridion Event System and also from the link shared by Raj. You can also refer to 'https://tridionwithanupam.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/get-started-with-tridion-event-system' for mainly setting up Event system and debugging options.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Raj, Rick, Anupam for the links. I am new to Tridion so thought of knowing the steps to get the process and attach it with my code (machine).

With that I found some thing too from SDL Site.

[processes to Attach](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_C17867B9613E4D1CAAAAF8A856EF50B4)

And steps (not the one exactly I needed but it helped to found the trick- no need to have remote debugger installed in CMS just copy paste of exe from developers machine in CMS works)

[Steps](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_C17867B9613E4D1CAAAAF8A856EF50B4#docid=task_D76A55C77B39455C88BA8159131156AC&filename=DebuggingDotNETAssemblyTBBsRemotely.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_D76A55C77B39455C88BA8159131156AC)

Comment: Great, sounds good. But make sure to put in detailed response/comment which helps to understand it better. Hope you understand !!